# Error Promise.all() attribute is not assignable to parameter

Tags: typescript, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am having some difficulty making an array of promises. I have the following cloud function

```
export const updateUser = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
    const userID : string = Authentication.authenticate(context);
    Validator.validateString('displayName', data['displayName']);
    Validator.validateString('photoURL', data['photoURL']);

    const userInfo = {
        displayName:data['displayName'],
        photoURL:data['photoURL'],
    };

    const userReference = await firestore.collection('users').doc(userID);
    const promises = [];
    promises.push(admin.auth().updateUser(userID, {displayName:userInfo.displayName, photoURL:userInfo.photoURL}));
    promises.push(userReference.update(userInfo));
    await Promise.all<admin.auth.UserRecord, FirebaseFirestore.WriteResult>(promises);
});
```

but `Promise.all<admin.auth.UserRecord, FirebaseFirestore.WriteResult>(promises);` give the following error

```
Argument of type '(Promise<WriteResult> | Promise<UserRecord>)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly [UserRecord | PromiseLike<UserRecord>, WriteResult | PromiseLike<WriteResult>]'.
  Type '(Promise<WriteResult> | Promise<UserRecord>)[]' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly [UserRecord | PromiseLike<UserRecord>, WriteResult | PromiseLike<WriteResult>]': 0, 1ts(2345)
```

But why? I matched the return type of the the promises. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the types of your promises are lost after you push them into the `promises` array, which is essentially untyped (no type means `any` in TypeScript).

In your specific case here, it doesn't even matter what the types of those promises are, because you aren't doing anything with them other than returning them to the caller.  The callable function will automatically serialize them and send them back to the client.  I suggest just abandoning the types altogether and writing this:

```
return Promise.all(promises)
```

Note that you actually have to `return` the promise.  You can't just `await` it.  The client won't receive any values otherwise.

If you wanted to retain the types, you'd want to avoid pushing them into an untyped array, more like this:

```
const p1 = admin.auth().updateUser(userID, {displayName:userInfo.displayName, photoURL:userInfo.photoURL}));
const p2 = userReference.update(userInfo));
return Promise.all<admin.auth.UserRecord, FirebaseFirestore.WriteResult>([p1, p2]);
```